# How are offerings communicated from Agni to other gods?

Tags: gods, food, agni, homam

During homa we give food to Agni (pour oblations in fire) but how will that food reach those particular deva's?

Comment: when you send home a Rs.100 through DD/money-order, how does it reach your parents in a different city instantly? does your 100 rupee note physically travel to the destination ? No. the post-office acts as a broker, and once he gets money from you, sends money to your parents. similarly, Agni has account in deva-loka from which he'll give this havir-bhaga to devas.

Comment: YajnaAgni is considered as mouth of Devatas. Let me see verses supporting this.

Comment: "अग्निं प्रथमं देवतानां यजति, अग्निर्वै देवानां मुखम्।।”  - Agnirvai Devatanam Mukham .(शां.ब्रा. ३.६)" Shankhayana Brahmana.

Answer (score 3):

Manusmriti [3.76](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu03.htm) says:

> 76. **An oblation duly thrown into the fire, reaches the sun**; from the sun comes rain, from rain food, therefrom the living creatures (derive
>       their subsistence).

When it reaches the Sun, it means it has reached the abode of the Devas.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about how Agni delivers or transfers the food  offered as   oblations to  the  gods who are residing in Swarga loka or Dyu-Loka.

In Hinduism  Agni is called as a messenger between earth and heaven. Agni receives the oblations offered on earth in Yajna , Homa etc. and transfers them to various gods residing in dyu loka or heaven.

> मूर्धा दिवो नाभिरग्निः पर्थिव्या अथाभवदरती रोदस्योः | 
>  तं तवा
>   देवासो.अजनयन्त देवं वैश्वानर जयोतिरिदार्याय || [**RV 1.59.2**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01059.htm) ||
>
> mūrdhā divo nābhiraghniḥ pṛthivyā athābhavadaratī rodasyoḥ | 
>  taṃ
>   tvā devāso.ajanayanta devaṃ vaiśvānara jyotiridāryāya ||
>
> 2 The forehead of the sky, earth's centre, **Agni became the messenger
>   of earth and heaven.** Vaiśvānara, the Deities produced thee, a God,
>   to be a light unto the Ārya.
>
> ---
>
> यो अग्निः करव्यवाहनः पितॄन यक्षद रताव्र्धः |  
>   परेदुहव्यानि वोचति देवेभ्यश्च पित्र्भ्य आ || [**RV 10.16.11**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10016.htm)  ||
>
> yo aghniḥ kravyavāhanaḥ pitṝn yakṣad ṛtāvṛdhaḥ | 
>  preduhavyāni
>   vocati devebhyaśca pitṛbhya ā ||
>
> 11 With offerings meet let Agni bring the Fathers who support the Law.
>   **Let him announce oblations paid to Fathers and to Deities.**

---

In Shankhyayana Brahmana 3.6  Its said that Agni is mouth of gods. I.e. He is the mouth by which the Gods eat the sacrifice; and his flames are spoons with which he sprinkles the Gods, and he also consumes the offerings himself. oblations is poured in the mouth of agni who then  becomes mouth of the gods

> अग्निं प्रथमं देवतानां यजति | अग्निर्वै देवानां मुखम्।। ||
>
> Agnirvai Devatanam Mukham
>
> He is mouth of gods

---

Besides the another answer by which way agni transfers oblations offered here in homa to gods in Dyu loka   is given by Adi-Shankaracharya in his commentary on [**The Brihadaranyaka Upanishad - Adhaya 6 - Brahmana 2 - Mantra 9**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc122212.html) - "The Process of Rebirth" , where he is explaining the process of how food offered in Agnihotra Homa is transferred to Dyu loka.

> These two oblations of the Agnihotra, after being offered, depart.
>   They enter the sky, of which they make an Āhavanīya fire,[7] with air
>   as its fuel, and the sun's rays its white oblation. They offer
>   libations to the sky and depart from there. They enter heaven, of
>   which they make an Āhavanīya fire, with the sun as its fuel,’ and so
>   on (Ś. XI. vi. ii. 6-7). Of course these oblations of the Agnihotra
>   depart together with their accessories. Whatever accessories they are
>   known to possess here, such as the Āhavanīya fire, fuel, smoke,
>   cinder, sparks and the articles of oblation, they take along with them
>   as they leave this world for heaven. There, although everything is in
>   an undifferentiated state during the dissolution of the world, those
>   ingredients retain their separate existence in an extremely subtle
>   form—the fire remaining as fire, the fuel as fuel, the smoke as smoke,
>   the cinder as cinder, the sparks as sparks and the articles of
>   oblation as articles of oblation such as milk. That ceremony of the
>   Agnihotra with its accessories, which never ceases to exist, but
>   remains in a subtle form known as the Apūrva,[8] reappears in its old
>   form at the time of manifestation, by making use of the sky etc. as
>   the Āhavanīya fire and so on as before. The ceremony of the Agnihotra
>   is like that even to-day.

**The process is in brief** - When we offer oblations to gods in Yajna or Homa say like Agnihotra are consumed by Agni and then Agni himself acting as mouth of gods  receives those on the behalf of gods.

The oblations offered are get converted  and are carried out with the help of medium like    smoke, cinder, sparks etc. leave the world for Dyu loka . But although they are converted they retain their sukshma rupa or extreme subtle form while. For them to reach to dyu loka there need some carrier , So they first enter into sky and they make the sky as fire with air as fuel and suns rays as oblations.  From there they enter into heaven making  heaven as fire and sun as fuel and so on..

Although the scope of the above citing of  Brihadaranyaka Upanishad  is different i.e. it is stating the process of rebirth , but from shankara's commentary we get a fair idea about how actually the food items are transferred to gods in heaven.

Comment: Nice explanation and you are saying that each and every substance have sukshma rupa even though its inert and it exists after destroying into fire and that sukshma rupa goes to devata

Comment: Actually yes , the commentary suggests us that the substances even milk etc. retain their original form in subtle state and they again get transformed in the process and gain their original form as they reach to devas. In the same manner the food is brought here by gods  through rain , air , sunlight etc. its a cycle. :-)

Comment: can u send me some discourses or books link regarding this topic

Comment: @harishandroid Yes , i will try. Most of the information regarding this topic is not at one place in Scriptures , instead it can be found in Brahman granthas , pueanas as well as in Vedanta & mimansa and itihaas also.What i will do is whenever i will come across some verse ,i will inform you about that.Also about articles.